# Copy files from a folder in a directory to a new folder

Tags: bash, shell

- I want to copy files from one folder to another folder, I have files in binary data, txt files and etc in a folder.
- But for example my files are stored in a folder1 lets say the script should make a newfolder with the name folder2

I have tried with the following code but I didnt succeed

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in /home/mj/New Folder/*inp
    name="$(basename "$file" .inp)"

for file in ~/home/mj/New Folder/*coor
    name="$(basename "$file".dcd)"


for file in ~/home/mj/New Folder/*pdb
    name="$(basename "$file".coor)


mkdir -p /home/mj/New Folder/"$name"

    cp "$file" "/home/mj/New Folder/"$name"

done
```

Comment: this is python? -- use shutil

Comment: OP is likely open to a python solution to the problem, even though they've attempted a bash solution

Comment: I need a bash solution or python,, but its better to have a bash solution,...

Comment: I need a bash code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you seem to be trying to mix 3 loops into one. You need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in /home/mj/New Folder/*inp ; do
    name="$(basename "$file" .inp)"
    mkdir -p /home/mj/New Folder/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/home/mj/New Folder/$name"
done

for file in ~/home/mj/New Folder/*coor
    name="$(basename "$file".dcd)"
    mkdir -p /home/mj/New Folder/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/home/mj/New Folder/$name"
done

for file in ~/home/mj/New Folder/*pdb
    name="$(basename "$file".coor)"
    mkdir -p /home/mj/New Folder/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/home/mj/New Folder/$name"
done
```

Be also careful with your quotes which did not  match in the script you submitted.
Of course there are numerous ways to make this better and avoid repeating the loop three times, but I guess this is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you but its doing something strange making two folder New and Folder separatley and not copying the files with these extensions.... e.g if I have a folder1 having files somename.inp , somename.restart.coor and somename.dcd files how will I copy these files in to automatically made newfolder say folder2 ,, and please how can I make this code better ,, thank you

Comment: If you have New and Folder created separately then it means your quotes do not match (make sure /home/mj/New Folder/$name is enclosed in ")

Comment: now making the folder2 but its not copying the files in the folder2

Comment: for file in /home/mj/folder1/ ; do
    name="$(basename "$file" .psf)"
    mkdir -p /home/mj/folder2/"$name"
    cp "$file" "/home/mj/folder2/$name"
done

Comment: Iam successful in copying the files in to new folder but for every copied file it is making a separate folder , it should only copy the files from folder1 and make a folder 2 and only copy the files from 1 to folder2...